# CoreStorage volume not journaled

Tags: macos, core-storage, hfs+

I have an interesting case on an iMac. It has a fusion drive and at some point it stoped booting up. Booting up in single-user mode, I tried to mount the boot partition but it gave an error "**permission denied**" (though it's not encrypted).
I rebooted from an installation media and tried to use diskutil to check for errors. Repairing the volume failed after it attempted to resize the volume with the message "**resize support required, such as HFS+ with Journaling enabled**". I checked the file system and indeed, it *wasn't JOURNALED*. The "Enable Journaling" option in disk utility wasn't available despite having unmounted the volume. Terminal was also of no help since the *"diskutil enableJournal" doesn't seem to work on core storage volumes*.

**So my question is:** Is it possible to reenable journaling on a CoreStorage logical volume?

Diskutil output:

```
Administrators-iMac:~ admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         24.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            23.6 GB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +1.0 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2
                                 2467C7ED-B641-4F8A-90B1-AC9F2454D2CC
                                 Unencrypted
```

Diskutil cs list output:

```
Administrators-iMac:~ admin$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 28A4A3C1-E63B-4613-A15F-0B4A5E7980EB
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1022898851840 B (1.0 TB)
    Free Space:   298684416 B (298.7 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume F49340A2-815F-4710-9780-7567582C815E
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     23553724416 B (23.6 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 899749E3-2E9E-4F73-86AA-5DE7525C15B7
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345127424 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family D014E2BE-20A4-4EB1-ABBF-57DF8DBF7EDC
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 2467C7ED-B641-4F8A-90B1-AC9F2454D2CC
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1021994057728 B (1.0 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Sparse
```

First Aid Error:

```
Checking for overcommitted space in Logical Volume Group

Fixing size of logical volume to fill logical volume group.

File system resize support required, such as HFS+ with Journaling enabled.
Operation failed…
```

Comment: Would you be amenable to posting `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`?

Comment: posted the outputs